# Angular ng-pattern to allow one dot

Tags: regex, angularjs, ng-pattern

How to allow on text input , numbers and one dot using Angular?

I have this on html :

```
  <input type="text"  ng-pattern="/^[0-9.]*$/" />
```

But I  want to allow just one dot.

Any idea?

Comment: you mean this `^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$`

Comment: post some valid and invalid examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to allow decimal or integer numbers.

```
^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$
```

Comment: I want to allow dot but not must to be  dot. valid ex: 1.1,  22.22 , 3 .      Invalid ex: 2.2.2 ,  .1

Comment: then use the first regex.